# Pass Azure DevOps Build Pipeline runtime variable values into a powershell GUI?

Tags: powershell, variables, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I have set up a powershell script which is designed to trigger an Azure DevOps build pipeline using the REST API and allows me to pass in runtime variables that are needed to control which tasks are run within it. See this script below (with the sensitive details removed).

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic [Redacted PAT]")
$headers.Add("Cookie", "VstsSession=%7B%22PersistentSessionId%22%3A%22404b5f44-9de5-4f0c-9f5d-0bd588e89d68%22%2C%22PendingAuthenticationSessionId%22%3A%2200000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%22%2C%22CurrentAuthenticationSessionId%22%3A%2200000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%22%2C%22SignInState%22%3A%7B%7D%7D")

$body = @{
    stagesToSkip = @{}
    resources = @{
        repositories = @{
            "self" = "@{
                refName = 'refs/heads/master'}"
            }
        }
        
    templateParameters = @{}
    variables = @{
        'variable1' = @{
            value = ''
        }
    'variable2' = @{
            value = ''
        }
        'variable3' = @{
            value = ''
        }
    'variable4' = @{
            value = ''
        }
    'variable5' = @{
            value = ''
        }
    'variable6'= @{
            value = ''
        }
    'variable7'= @{
            value = ''
        }
    'variable8'= @{
            value = ''
        }
    'variable9'= @{
            value = ''
        }
    'variable10'= @{
            value = ''
        }
    'variable11'= @{
            value = ''
        }
    'variable12'= @{
            value = ''
        }
    'variable13'= @{
            value = ''
        }
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json

$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://dev.azure.com/[myorganisation]/[myproject]/_apis/pipelines/[pipelineID]/runs?api-version=7.0' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body
$response | ConvertTo-Json`
```

This works ok, I can specify a value for the required variables and it passes them through when the script is run.

I want to expand on this however and make this something that can be run from a simple GUI. I have been experimenting with using the System.Windows.Forms assembly to achieve this and while I can technically run the build pipeline with it, I can't figure out a way to pass in the runtime variable values.

I've tried setting up text boxes within the GUI which link back to a particular variable but the values dont get passed in when the pipeline runs.

This is the script I have used, which I admittedly grabbed from our semi-reliable AI friend chat-gpt, given my lack of experience in this area:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Define the form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Azure DevOps Build Trigger"
$form.Width = 400
$form.Height = 500

# Define the variables
$variables = @{
    'variable1' = ''
    'variable2' = ''
    'variable3' = ''
    'variable4' = ''
    'variable5' = ''
    'variable6' = ''
    'variable7' = ''
    'variable8' = ''
    'variable9' = ''
    'variable10' = ''
    'variable11' = ''
    'variable12' = ''
    'variable13' = ''
}

# Function to create a label and text box for a variable
function CreateVariableControl($labelText, $top) {
    $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label.Text = $labelText
    $label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, $top)
    $label.AutoSize = $true

    $textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150, $top)
    $textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)

    $form.Controls.Add($label)
    $form.Controls.Add($textBox)

    # Add an event handler to update the variable value when the text box changes
    $script:variableName = $labelText
    $textBox.Add_TextChanged({
        $variables[$script:variableName] = $textBox.Text
    })
}

# Add controls for each variable
$top = 30
CreateVariableControl 'variable1' $top
$top += 30
CreateVariableControl 'variable2' $top
$top += 30
CreateVariableControl 'variable3' $top
$top += 30
CreateVariableControl 'variable4' $top
$top += 30
CreateVariableControl 'variable5' $top
$top += 30
CreateVariableControl 'variable6' $top
$top += 30
CreateVariableControl 'variable7' $top
$top += 30
CreateVariableControl 'variable8' $top
$top += 30
CreateVariableControl 'variable9' $top
$top += 30
CreateVariableControl 'variable10' $top
$top += 30
CreateVariableControl 'variable11' $top
$top += 30
CreateVariableControl 'variable12' $top
$top += 30
CreateVariableControl 'variable13' $top

$buttonRun = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$buttonRun.Text = "Run"
$buttonRun.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150, $top + 30)
$buttonRun.Add_Click({
    # Read the content of the TriggerBuild.ps1 script with error handling
    $triggerBuildScriptPath = "BuildPipelinePowershellScript.ps1"
    try {
        $triggerBuildScriptContent = Get-Content $triggerBuildScriptPath -Raw -ErrorAction Stop
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Error reading TriggerBuild.ps1 script: $_"
        return
    }

    # Concatenate the TriggerBuild script content with the entered variables
    $scriptWithVariables = $triggerBuildScriptContent
    foreach ($variableName in $variables.Keys) {
        $scriptWithVariables = $scriptWithVariables -replace "\$$variableName", "`$$variableName = '$($variables[$variableName])'"
    }

    # Execute the TriggerBuild script with the concatenated content
    Invoke-Expression $scriptWithVariables
})

$form.Controls.Add($buttonRun)
$form.ShowDialog()
```

This is just designed to be a very simple GUI with text boxes where the variable values can be entered and then a 'run' button is hit to trigger the build pipeline.

I've tried formatting this GUI script in multiple different ways, including having the build pipeline script included in the same script, but end up with the same behaviour everytime (i.e. the build runs but the runtime variable values aren't passed in).

My expectation would be that from the GUI this script creates, I can enter a value for the required variable(s) and when I hit run, the build pipeline runs and also passes in the specified values for the corresponding runtime variables.

As an example: [image]

Which would result in the build pipeline running as per the example here:

[image]

Instead, in its current configuration, all variables show 'undefined'.

Comment: Please check the `$scriptWithVariables` content to make sure it has correct variable value list.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT Sorry I'm not sure what would be considered 'correct' in this context, is there something specific you can advise as needing to be changed? Or alternatively, if you have any suggestions on alternative ways of achieving the intended setup it would be appreciated.

Comment: You are executing `Invoke-Expression $scriptWithVariables` to run the pipeline, hence you can `Write-Host` the content check if the variable list is correctly replaced. Not familar with Powershell GUI, but if you defined in powershell variable list, you can replace the variable via command below : $scriptWithVariables = $scriptWithVariables -replace "$variableName = @{\s*value = """, "$variableName = @{ value = `"$($variables[$variableName])`" }".

Comment: It shows `undefined` in pipeline log, it's because the variable value is empty.

Comment: Hi @Elliot, is there any update? You can also follow the sample below from wenbo for a check, it works for me.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT I've now provided the resolution that I found for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to modify the code and format it as per the ADO build API (and added tick boxes):

```
if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
    $var0 = $comboBox0.Text
    $var1 = $textBox1.Text
    $var2 = if ($checkBox2.Checked) {'Yes'} else {'No'}
    $var3 = if ($checkBox3.Checked) {'Yes'} else {'No'}
    $var4 = if ($checkBox4.Checked) {'Yes'} else {'No'}
    $var5 = if ($checkBox5.Checked) {'Yes'} else {'No'}
    $var6 = if ($checkBox6.Checked) {'Yes'} else {'No'}
    $var7 = if ($checkBox7.Checked) {'Yes'} else {'No'}
    $var8 = if ($checkBox8.Checked) {'Yes'} else {'No'}
    $var9 = if ($checkBox9.Checked) {'Yes'} else {'No'}
    $var10 = if ($checkBox10.Checked) {'Yes'} else {'No'}
    $var11 = if ($checkBox11.Checked) {'Yes'} else {'No'}
    $var12 = if ($checkBox12.Checked) {'Yes'} else {'No'}
    $var13 = if ($checkBox13.Checked) {'Yes'} else {'No'}

    Write-Host "variable0: $var0"
    Write-Host "variable1: $var1"
    Write-Host "variable2: $var2"
    Write-Host "variable3: $var3"
    Write-Host "variable4: $var4"
    Write-Host "variable5: $var5"
    Write-Host "variable6: $var6"
    Write-Host "variable7: $var7"
    Write-Host "variable8: $var8"
    Write-Host "variable9: $var9"
    Write-Host "variable10: $var10"
    Write-Host "variable11: $var11"
    Write-Host "variable12: $var12"
    Write-Host "variable13: $var13"

$body= @"
    {
      
    "definition":{"id":22},
    "sourceBranch":"refs/heads/$var0",
    "reason":1,
    "demands":[],
    "parameters":"{\"system.debug\":\"false\",\"variable1\":\"$var1\",\"variable2\":\"$var2\","variable3\":\"$var3\",\"variable4\":\"$var4\",\"variable5\":\"$var5\",\"variable6\":\"$var6\",\"variable7\":\"$var7\",\"variable8\":\"$var8\",\"variable9\":\"$var9\",\"variable10\":\"$var10\",\"variable11\":\"$var11\",\"variable12\":\"$var12\",\"variable13\":\"$var13\"}"
      
    }  
"@
    $token = "TOKEN"
    $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
    $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    $headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic $token")
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://dev.azure.com/OrgName/Project/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.1-preview.7' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body
    $response | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

##### Prerequisites:

If you want trigger the pipeline running with variable using Rest API, confirm that you un-select the variable limition in `Project Settings -> Pipelines -> Settings` [docs Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/inputs?view=azure-devops) [image] .

if not modify above setting, you may get an error even all your powershell UI works well.

> Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"See
> https://aka.ms/AzPipelines/SettingVariablesAtQueueTime - You can't set
> the following variables (variable2,variable0,variable1). If you want
> able to set these variables

##### 1. my sample code for you:

###### form.ps1

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Data Entry Form'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
$okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$okButton.Text = 'OK'
$okButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $okButton
$form.Controls.Add($okButton)

$cancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$cancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,120)
$cancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$cancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$cancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $cancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($cancelButton)
##
$cnt = 2
$textBoxArray = @()
foreach($item in @(0..$cnt)){

    $labelPositionY = ($item - 1)*25 + 30
    $textBoxPositionY = ($item - 1)*25 + 30

    $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,$labelPositionY)
    $label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60,20)
    $label.Text = 'Variable{0}: ' -f $item
    $form.Controls.Add($label)

    $textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,$textBoxPositionY)
    $textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,20)
    $form.Controls.Add($textBox)

    $textBoxArray += $textBox
}

$form.Topmost = $true

# $form.Add_Shown({$textBox[0].Select()})
$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    foreach($item in $textBoxArray){
        $var = $item.Text
        Write-Host $var
    }
    . .\runPipelineWithVariables.ps1 -Variable0 $textBoxArray[0].Text -Variable1 $textBoxArray[1].Text -Variable2 $textBoxArray[2].Text
}
```

###### runPipelineWithVariables.ps1

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter()]
    [string]$Variable0,
    [Parameter()]
    [string]$Variable1,
    [Parameter()]
    [string]$Variable2
)
##
$userName = "xxx"
$personalAccessToken = "xxx"
#
$organizationName = "xxx"
$projectName = "xxx"
$pipelineId = 111
#
$basicAuth = ("{0}:{1}" -f $userName, $personalAccessToken)
$basicAuth = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($basicAuth)
$basicAuth = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($basicAuth)
$headers = @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $basicAuth) }
##
$headers = Get-AzureDevOpsHeaders -UserName $userName -PersonalAccessToken $personalAccessToken

$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{0}/{1}/_apis/pipelines/{2}/runs?api-version=7.1-preview.1" -f $organizationName, $projectName, $pipelineId

$body = @{
    resources = @{
        repositories = @{
            'self' = @{
                refName = 'refs/heads/master'
                }
            }
        }
    variables = @{
        'variable0' = @{
            isSecret = $false
            value = $Variable0
        }
        'variable1' = @{
            isSecret = $false
            value = $Variable1
        }
        'variable2' = @{
            isSecret = $false
            value = $Variable2
        }
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method 'Post' -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

replace the un-given parameters in `runPipelineWithVariables.ps1` and run `form.ps1`, it will ask to input the `variable0, variables1, variables2.`

###### 2. you may need a yaml like this to debug the variables:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo "variable0 is, $(variable0)"
- script: echo "variable1 is, $(variable1)"
- script: echo "variable2 is, $(variable2)"
```

###### 3. my test result:

[image]

[image]